# Java Logging in to a website that uses complex javascript

Tags: java, phantomjs, httpclient, htmlunit, rhino

I'd first like to start by saying, I've managed this using phantomJS and Selenium. I load phantomjs, load the url (sports.coral.co.uk) and then check my balance. I am however trying to find a more lightweight option.

I have tried manually sending http get/post requests using apache's HttpClient. Monitoring the login process, using postman for chrome, shows 4 requests sent once the login button has been pressed. I have tried editing and re-sending them using postman. However, from what I can tell there's a requestID that gets sent along with the requests. This is generated using the javascript on the page.

```
var requestId = (new Date().getTime()) + Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000);
            var failedTimer = setTimeout('iapiRequestFailed(' + requestId + ')', iapiConf['loginDomainRetryInterval'] * 1000);
            iapiRegisterRequestId(requestId, iapiCALLOUT_MESSAGES, failedTimer, request[3], request[4], request[5]);
            return;
```

It looks like the original ID is a random generated number, that then gets registered using another javascript function. I'm guessing the login is partly failing due to me not being able to provide an acceptable requestID. When I re-send the old requests the user is part logged in. Once i click on my account it says an error occurred. The only explanation would be the requestID.

I then decided to give HtmlUnit a go. This seems like the type of thing I require. I did some research on using HttpClient with a javascript engine, such as Rhino and it seems HtmlUnit is the tool for that. 
Before I even try to log in to the page, I get errors caused by the javascript on the page.

Heres the simple bit of code I use to connect to the page;

```
@Test
public void htmlunit() throws Exception {
    LogFactory.getFactory().setAttribute("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");

    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF);
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.commons.httpclient").setLevel(Level.OFF);

    WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);


    HtmlPage page = client.getPage("http://sports.coral.co.uk");
    System.out.println(page.asText());
    client.close();
}
```

When I comment out the LogFactory bit I can see that there are loads of Warnings thrown,

```
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
Feb 09, 2016 4:33:34 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript isExecutionNeeded
```

WARNING: Script is not JavaScript (type: application/ld+json, language: ). Skipping execution. etc...

I'm guessing this means that HtmlUnit isn't compatible with the javascript thats being executed on the page?
I'm not very good with javascript and the scripts on the page are obfuscated, which makes it even harder to read. What I don't understand is, why does the JS get executed without error when using phantomJS or chromeDriver but not HtmlUnit? Is it because the Rhino engine isn't good enough to execute it? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

This code will turn off all the javascript warnings caused by the htmlunit library and not by your code.

```
LogFactory.getFactory().setAttribute("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");

java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF); 
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.commons.httpclient").setLevel(Level.OFF);

WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);

HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://sports.coral.co.uk");
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this code and it just hangs when I use BrowserVersion.Chrome. It's been executing for well over 2 minutes.
When I try Edge or leaving it default it fails with the same error. Chrome and firefox give the same results

Comment: It's weird, i tried this code and it worked. Did you try to print the content of the page? `System.out.println(page.asText());` And don't forget to close the webclient windows at the end: `webClient.close();`

Comment: did you try it with the same url? "https://sports.coral.co.uk" ? It seems that the javascript on the page isn't quite compatible with HtmlUnit for whatever reason and isn't being executed properly. It took 26 minutes to load the page earlier.

Comment: Yes, I tried with the same url, but it took around 8 minutes. When you open the url in the browser, is it long to load?

Comment: When I open it in chrome it takes around 10 seconds to fully load. Thanks for trying. I'm looking in to JBrowserDriver currently